# flexbox stretch two columns containing unequal number of items in, equally, within a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have two columns contained within a row. Within column A, I have three items. In column B I have 4 items.

I would like both columns to be of equal height, with the items distributed evenly within the columns.

I've tried `align-content: stretch;` on `.col` but doesn't do it.

```css
header{
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    border: 10px solid purple;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.row {
    width: auto;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.col {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2.5px solid tomato;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flex-item {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<!-- Row a -->
 <div class="row">
<!-- Col L -->
  <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
  </div>
<!-- /Col L -->
<!-- Col R -->
  <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
  </div>
<!-- /Col R -->
 </div>
<!-- /Row a -->
</div>
```

Comment: Note, it is meaningless to use prefixed `display: flex;` unless you also add prefix to the other Flexbox properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented out the `align-items: center` on the `.row` and changed the `justify-content` property on the `.col` to the value of `space-between`:

```css
header{
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    border: 10px solid purple;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.row {
    width: auto;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    /*align-items: center; / the default value of the align-items property is stretch, which is exactly what you want */
    justify-content: center;
}
.col {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2.5px solid tomato;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between; /* modified / items are now evenly distributed */
}
.flex-item {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<!-- Row a -->
 <div class="row">
<!-- Col L -->
  <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
  </div>
<!-- /Col L -->
<!-- Col R -->
  <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
   <div class="flex-item text-center"><p>A</p></div>
  </div>
<!-- /Col R -->
 </div>
<!-- /Row a -->
</div>
```